# when convergence in measure implies convergence almost surely

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

If I have a discrete measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$, that is when $\Omega$ is countable and $\mathcal{A}$ is the $\sigma$-field over $\Omega$ containing all the subsets of $\Omega$, then convergence in measure over this measure space implies convergence almost surely.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: yeah, this is my problem. I dont know how to prove it. This doesnt happen in general measure space, although almost sure convergence imply convergence in measure. I have gone through several counterexamples that say that convergence in measure doesnt imply convergence almost everywhere but could not find out what difference a discrete measure space can make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convergence almost everywhere is equivalent to convergence at each point with positive measure.  Suppose there is a point $x$ with positive measure such that $(f_n(x))$ does not converge to $f(x)$.  Then $\mu(\{x\})$ is a fixed positive constant that will keep $(f_n)$ from converging to $f$ in measure.